# System F Church numerals in Agda

Tags: agda, lambda-calculus, church-encoding, system-f, typed-lambda-calculus

I would like to test some definitions in system F using Agda as my typechecker and evaluator.

My first attempt to introduce Church natural numbers was by writing

```
Num = forall {x} -> (x -> x) -> (x -> x)
```

Which would be used just like a regular type alias:

```
zero : Num
zero f x = x
```

However the definition of `Num` does not type(kind?)check. What is the most proper way to make it working and be as close as possible to the system F notation?

Comment: What is the error? What if you place `{-# OPTIONS --type-in-type #-}` at the top of the file?

Comment: The error I get for this particular example is 
`piSort (univSort _3)
(λ _ → piSort (piSort _3 (λ _ → _3)) (λ _ → piSort _3 (λ _ → _3)))
!=< Set → Set of type
univSort
(piSort (univSort _3)
 (λ _ → piSort (piSort _3 (λ _ → _3)) (λ _ → piSort _3 (λ _ → _3))))
when checking that the expression ∀ {x} → (x → x) → x → x has type
Set → Set`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following would typecheck

```
Num : Set₁
Num = forall {x : Set} -> (x -> x) -> (x -> x)

zero : Num
zero f x = x
```

but as you see `Num : Set₁`, this might become a problem and you'll need `--type-in-type`

Comment: How do you write `Set₁`?

Comment: @radrow `Set\_1` in the emacs mode. or alternatively you can use the ascii `Set 1`